# Directive talks to controller but cannot call functions residing in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I have a directive which needs to call functions from the Main controller but everytime i try to reference a function inside the directive nothing happens because it's undefined. When I access a value for instance $scope.someProp I do get the desired response but not when I call the function.

Anyone else who's faced this issue? Any Suggestions?

Comment: Can you show the code for the directive and controller?

Comment: Hello Gruff, sorry for not getting back earlier, here's a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/BEozKyRZ0rJMz2e0jyp0?p=preview . I'm trying to access the startChange() function from the controller. I want to dynamically insert the confirmation element and have it inherit the behavior of the directive and subsequently fire the function which the confirmation accesses from the controller. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few things:

- Your controller exposes startChange function on the scope, so you need to call it on the scope, i.e. 'scope.startChange()' from within the directive and not 'startChange()'
- Your confirmation directive uses isolate scope which is great if you know what youre doing, but in essence it is cutting you off from the parents scope on which you are trying to call a function

You got 3 options in this case

1. Use Scope $emit/$broadcast to share state
2. use isolate scope
   and '&' syntax to execute an expression in the context of parent
   scope -- example http://plnkr.co/edit/8UEDpoS6ie5qtFc8e08h?p=preview
3. not use isolate scope and execute the startChange function
   on the scope of the directive which is the same as scope of the
   controller -- example: http://plnkr.co/edit/h1T2QNOL7wGNG0eprLMC?p=preview

Comment: I've tried isolating the scope with the `startChange: '&'`. the absense of $scope. while accessing the function was a typo. That doesn't work either. in the plnkr you've posted using the third approach, the function does not fire from within the directive. It fires when you click on the button which already has an ng-click therefore it's still not the directive communicating with the controller. Do you have something else in mind? here's the updated example with an isolated scope http://plnkr.co/edit/9ZQ7UfeBHmByOJftDIx9?p=preview Thanks for your time.

Comment: my bad, i had a typo in the directive code, try visiting that plunker i linked to now

Comment: Awh great Vladimir! Can you tell me a way which would let me append the `confirmation` directive from the `updater` directive and still have this nested function fire. (Basically the confirmation directive just working like it would independently) I've been trying to figure this out since the past 2 days. :P haha

Comment: Im not very clear to what your updated directive does or any interactions in your code. Generally speaking if your directives need to share state, they should do it either via a service or a controller using 'require' attribute.

Comment: I don't think it's a case of sharing state, I might have confused you there. What I mean is appending the `<confirmation>` element in DOM from the updater directive. (I have it setup to tap into an event, which it does in my real app) I just need that element inserted and then it'll have the same functionality(as defined in it's respective directive) . `require` from my understanding is accessing directives from preceding  directives, which is not what I want, I just want to append it from the first one.

Comment: The fact that I chose to use an isolated scope, is why I couldn't use the functions in the controller. I wish that was documented well . Any help on the above problem?

Comment: @SinSync, i provided an example on how to access parent's scope function from a directive with isolate scope. See a plunker next to example 2

Comment: Thanks a lot for that Vladimir! I've accepted the answer. Could you tell me how I can append a directive from another directive? The grey text is appended via the directive and I need it to have it's respective `confirmation` directive behavior.  Here's a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/OyBTYGTkMtxryFdDRwQN?p=preview Thanks.

Comment: You had a bunch of missing closing parens, problems with nested clauses and other stuff that an editor with a good linter would pick up. I recommend using Sublime and SublimeLinter. Here is the fixed plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/sV7qmxlJlO4lVOaFYyjv?p=preview

Comment: Hello thanks for that Vladimir, that's probably me missing that cos I was too desperate for a solution. :P Here's an updated Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/OyBTYGTkMtxryFdDRwQN?p=preview I want to append after my watch event returns true . I'm simulating that with a button, when you press the button, it should append the element created dynamically and inserted into the DOM, with it's bindings like the yellow element, which is already present in the DOM. The newly inserted element should inherit the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If you can change values, why not have your controller watch those values and run the function you need when they change?

```
$scope.$watch('myScopeVar', function(newValue, oldValue){
    if(oldValue !== newValue){
        $scope.someFunction();
    }
});
```

I'm not saying this is the best way to do this, but it should work. Beware of scope issues though. If your directive uses an isolated scope you may have to do this with a service that the directive changes the value in the service and the controller watches that service value as above. Again, not ideal, but should work.

Comment: I'll try that approach @Mbielski . I've posted a plnkr above, see if you think if that's the best way to do it. :)